# Pauli matrices: lower index vs upper index

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, conventions, notation, dirac-matrices

I have read some identities about the Pauli matrices in 4-vector notation and I am a little confused.
 as $$\sigma ^\mu=(I,\sigma ^i);\qquad \overline{\sigma}^\mu=(I,-\sigma ^i).$$

But what exactly is $\sigma _\mu $?

Comment: Actually, i found a description of how the Pauli matrices can construct the 4-dimensional Lorentz transformations, thus actually the Pauli matrices can act as basis vectors for the 4-dimensional space in some sense, in the "spinor" representation. The title of the book is "Quantum fractals" it is around pages 50-60. If I will have time I will write an answer from there

Answer (score 2):

For a Minkowski metric tensor $g$ as $\text{diag}(+---)$ (or the relativists' convention $\text{diag}(-+++)$ if you prefer), one can "lower" the index on the $\sigma^{\mu}$ if needed, just as if it was a true 4-vector (i.e. components of a 4-vector in the coordinate basis of Minkowski spacetime).

So you may write $\sigma_{\lambda} =:g_{\lambda\mu}\sigma^{\mu}$, but this is only to make sense of both $\sigma_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}\psi$ and $\sigma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi$. But the second variant is usually preferred, so "the low index sigma" is rare.